# Uploading Files using PHP Script to Web Hosting

Tags: java, php, android, cloud

I have written out a program which is designed to upload text files created from motion data information to a PHP cloud server that I have set up with 000webhost.com. Ive tried running it however it will not run for some reason. None of the sensor information is uploaded and there seems to be a problem me thinks on the server end. Is the error in the script or code? (or both?).

Edit: Yeah I know its not "great", I am still fairly new to coding and been trying to fiddle around with the code for a while (still working on it).

Program

```
package com.example.motionsense3;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import android.util.Log;


public class SaveTimer extends TimerTask
{
    String upLoadServerUri = null;
    final String uploadFilePath = "/data/data/com.example.motionsense3/";
    //final String uploadFileName = "????";

    private ArrayList<String> motionData;
    private ArrayList<String> motionDataClone;
    private Context context;

    public SaveTimer(ArrayList<String> motionData, MainActivity context) {
        this.motionDataClone = (ArrayList<String>) motionData.clone();
        this.motionData = motionData;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e("DIDUPLOADWORK", Boolean.toString(upload()));

    }

    private void save() {
         try {
             this.motionDataClone = (ArrayList<String>) motionData.clone();
             motionData.clear();

             FileOutputStream fileOutput = context.openFileOutput("scaninfo_" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date()).toString(), context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);//.write(s);
             for(String s : motionDataClone)
             {
                 fileOutput.write(s.getBytes());
             }
             fileOutput.close();


         } catch (Exception e) {

         }

        //save();

}


         public boolean upload(){//ArrayList<String> motion){//String sourceFileUri) {

             /************* Php script path ****************/
             upLoadServerUri = "motionsense.uphero.com/public_html/motiondata/UploadToServer.php";

          //String fileName = sourceFileUri;

          HttpURLConnection conn = null;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 


               try { 

                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                    String fileName = "scaninfo_" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date()).toString();
                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file; filename="
                                             + fileName + "" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                   for(String s : motionDataClone)
                   {
                       dos.write(s.getBytes());
                   }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
                   Log.e("SERVERRESPONSE", serverResponseMessage);
                   Log.e("SERVERRESPONSECODE", String.valueOf(serverResponseCode));

               }
               catch(Exception e){return false;}
               return true;
         }
    }
```

Php script

```
<?php

    $file_path = "motiondata/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: `catch(Exception e){e.printStacktrace(); return false;}` then read the logcat log ... i'm pretty sure (my magic orb said that) that your uri has no schema ... but, it also can be NetworkOnMainThread ... and hardcoded uploadFilePath looks suspiciously, too

Comment: We are not here to read through a wall of code and GUESS at what the problem is. Especially since you don't even bother instrumenting your code to check for success/failure. You're simply **ASSUMING** your uploads will always work in php, or that your android-side code is actually uploading properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just quickly glancing through the code, I believe your problem is here:

```
upLoadServerUri = "motionsense.uphero.com/public_html/motiondata/UploadToServer.php";
```

Basically you're trying to make a connection to UploadToServer.php through this public_html directory, however, this directory doesn't exist publically (it's where your "root" files are served from when accessing a website with '/'). Change to:

```
upLoadServerUri = "motionsense.uphero.com/motiondata/UploadToServer.php";
```

And you should be fine (assuming everything else works haha).